# Why do I see websites using (really long) base 64 pictures in their HTML?

Tags: html, web, base64, radix

What are the perks of doing it?

```
background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAKCAYAAAB10jRKAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAADBJREFUeNpEyqERADAIBMGbbwSH+qhA/6URXMyqBUhFBLIP6ip0ezk2zExqC58nwACVZwX67tO41gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="), url("data:image/jpeg;base64,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"); background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat, repeat; background-position: 0px 30px, 0% 0%, 0% 0%;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [advantages and disadvantages base64 image encode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736159/advantages-and-disadvantages-base64-image-encode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One advantage of data URLs is that the resulting image is available immediately without another round trip to the server. Some disadvantages of this method are that your image is not cached, and for larger images the encoded url can become quite long.

Source: [MDN - Using Images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images)