# Is page load time on mobile Android devices more compared to mobile iOS devices?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, operating-system, page-load-time

We noticed that page load time of our e-commerce web application on Android mobile devices is more compared to mobile iOS. However, on mobile Android devices, the page load time has improved over the time with the newer Operating System(OS) versions but still, it is almost double that of mobile iOS.

To analyze this we checked the request details(Webpagetest) of Android & iOS mobile devices and noticed that certain requests to our internal assets like js/CSS(CDN) are not seen for mobile iOS Webpagetest but are found for mobile Android Webpagetest. Also, we found some additional requests of images(internal assets - CDN) in mobile Android Webpagetest as compared to mobile iOS.

Can anybody let me know if the mobile page load time is related to OS or browser rendering the resources in an optimized way? If not, then could you please let me know if we could do something at our end to optimize and improve the page load time for mobile Android devices?

Any pointers provided would be helpful.

**Note:** The issue of page load time being more is noticed only on mobile devices whereas on desktop it looks fine w.r.t. OS/browser.

Regards,

Comment: what language is your page?

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalez Laravel

Answer (score 0):

We had had the same problem , and resolved with the next

- Convert the page in Single Page Application. it is permits  to reduce the time in load page

LInk
https://platzi.com/blog/una-single-page-application-no-es-tu-mejor-opcion/

- Convert the image to base64, it permits  to stay image in memory

link
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736159/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-base64-encoded-images)

- Use service worker

https://www.keycdn.com/blog/service-workers

- YOu can convert your web in a Progressive Web Apps

https://web.dev/what-are-pwas/

Other recommendation if you can use cache, it permits to reduce the load time