# How can I save a image in a session variable and then display in asp.net and sqlserver

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I' m new in this, also I'm new in Visual Basic and Sql Server, and I'm Chile...
Well, I have a question, I've been thinking for several days and can not solve.
I need to show an image in a web form of a client when he wants to see your information.

For that, I have the next sources:

Table Client

```
email(varchar), nameClient(varchar), nameImage(varchar)
```

Table Image

```
nameImage(varchar), image(image)
```

I have the next proc:

```
select c.email, c.nameClient, i.image
from Client as c join Image as i on c.nameImage=i.nameImage
```

In asp.net, I have a web Form as VerCliente.aspx, and in VerCliente.aspx.vb I have this:

```
Partial Class Default19
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    MostrarNombreCliente.Text = Session("correo")


End Sub

Protected Sub BotonMostrarPerfil_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BotonMostrarPerfil.Click
    Dim numero As Integer

    Dim dvSql As Data.DataView = DirectCast(SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), Data.DataView)
```

'of this way I do the connection to BD'

```
    If dvSql.Count > 0 Then
        numero = 1
```

'to display the information in the textbox Iam occupying session variables'

```
        Session("email") = dvSql(0).Item(0)
        MostrarEmail.Text = Session("email")

        Session("nombre") = dvSql(0).Item(1)
        MostrarNombreCompleto.Text = Session("nombre")
```

in VerCliente.aspx I have this , and I would display the image on it

```
asp:Image ID="MostrarImagen" runat="server" Height="191px" Width="270px" /
```

but I dont know how to occupy session variables here

```
        MostrarImagen.ImageUrl....(I dont know How )
```

I tried this but it does not work

```
        Session("imagen") = dvSql(0).Item(2)
        MostrarImagen.ImageUrl.ImageUrl =  Session("imagen")





    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

thank....bye!!!

Comment: you an use base64        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863631/vb-net-display-an-image-in-image-control-from-filepath-saved-in-an-access-datab

Comment: saving image url in a session variable will be more suitable.

Comment: An image size can be huge and saving it in the session could take up memory if you have a lot of users. Personally, I would store the image on the harddrive and save the filename in the database. You could then store the filename in the session if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after of I'm trying many times, finally I can to resolve my problem, howerer I think that the way that I did the new solution is quite different to how I had posed my problem, but the important is that my solution works fine...

Here is my solution, I hope that can to be of utility for you..

Thank for your comments!!!

Session("imagen") = dvSql(0).Item(8)

```
        If (Context.Session("imagen")) IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim image As Byte() = DirectCast(Context.Session("imagen"), Byte())

           Dim base64String As String = Convert.ToBase64String(image, 0, image.Length)
            Image1.ImageUrl = Convert.ToString("data:image/png;base64,") & base64String
            Image1.Visible = True
        End If
```