# Is possible to codify all images in base64 using nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: image, nginx, base64, reverse-proxy

i started using nginx some times ago and i want to speed up my webpages during loading. One of the problem that i can't fix is this, images loading time. I know what is base64 but i don't know how to codify all images in it on nginx. Can you help me? Thanks to all.

Comment: Have you had a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1575171/5014218 ?

Comment: And why do you think that would be faster? You should be using caching and other nginx features