# Jquery clone image without reloading

Tags: jquery, html, image, httprequest

When I clone an image, does the browser redownload the image? Chrome console says loaded from cache, but

When I look it on mobile browser (ios) there is a quite delay?

```js
$('#a').on('click', function() {
  $(this).clone().appendTo('body');
})
```

```css
#a {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="a" src="https://www.pcspecialist.co.uk/images/misc/right-pc.png" alt="">
```

Comment: errmm .. what's your question?

Comment: Can you see the question mark in the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue and I got around it by base64 encoding the image and using a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) to embed it in the html. With it embeded it's cloned without an additional request. However, be aware that there are trade offs to data URIs as discussed in this question: [How much faster is it to use inline/base64 images for a web site than just linking to the hard file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574961/how-much-faster-is-it-to-use-inline-base64-images-for-a-web-site-than-just-linki)

Answer (score 0):

On every `$(this).clone().appendTo('body');` the dom is repainting, since mobile devices have slower CPUs, of course the repainting will be slower.